# python rasterio and geoh5py incompatible

Tags: python, h5py, rasterio

Python 3.9 environment, I need to importh both geoh5py and rasterio, they are not compatible, all good if I only need to import geoh5py plus other libs, or only rasterio plus other libs, but if import both of them, regardless of order of import, it will give me an error:

```
import rasterio
import geoh5py
```

Error:

```
from rasterio._base import gdal_version    
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _base: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

or if import geoh5py first

```
from geoh5py.workspace import Workspace
     from . import _errors
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _errors: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new virtual environment and installing the packages with pip. This often helps with dependency issues. Here's how you can do it:

1. Create a new virtual environment:

```bash
python -m venv venv
```

2. Activate the virtual environment:

- On Windows:

```bash
venv\Scripts\activate
```

- On Mac/Linux:

```bash
source venv/bin/activate
```

3. Install `rasterio` and `geoh5py` using pip:

```bash
pip install rasterio geoh5py
```

Answer (score 0):

my current working solution is to install via pipwin

```py
pip install pipwin
pipwin install goal
pipwin install rasterio
pip install geoh5py
```

and all other libraries, this allows to import all packages successfully.